# Find numbers in String and compute, insert back in String (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to offer ingredient scaling feature in my recipe manager app.
Scaled result is for display purpose only and won't be persisted.

Let's say we have a fried rice recipe and its ingredient consists of `2 bowls of rice, 1 egg, 1 tbsp soy sauce` and this is for 2 serving(persons).

There are - and + buttons among this number '2' to increment/decrement serving which would look like
`- 2 +`

Whenever the - and + icons are pressed, it will run a function to get numbers from an ingredient String and get ingredient quantities of 1 serving. Recipe data can be saved in any serving size so for scaling I always need to start from 1 serving portion.
Based on my example here, 1 serving ingredient quantity should be `1 bowls of rice, 0.5 egg, 0.5 tbsp soy sauce`, thus `[1, 0.5, 0.5]`.

Then I can scale ingredient quantity based on user action.
So far I have figured out the following which gets the number string out of the whole ingredient string, make it into an array and convert it to Int array.

```
if recipe.ingredients != "" {
    let ingredientStr = recipe.ingredients
    let numStr = ingredientStr?.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
                    NSCharacterSet
                        .decimalDigitCharacterSet()
                        .invertedSet)
    let array = numStr!.filter({ $0 != "" })
    var intArray = array.map{ Int($0)! }
}
```

I've tried various ways to calculate numbers from here but failed to get expected numbers. What I haven't accomplished is:

- Get 1 serving quantities
- Scale quantities based on +, - action
- Insert the arithmetic result back in the original String to display

Comment: I think your are approaching this from the wrong end. Your data source should be some structure with all the ingredients (as strings) and amounts (as numbers), e.g. an array of structs. Then you can modify the amounts easily. From that data source you create the textual representation for display.

Comment: Yes you're right. The ideal data model is separating quantity and ingredient separately. But other than the scaling feature, I won't offer anything that deal with ingredient portions so I chose a simple way. There is a benefit of making it into a whole String like easier input on a mobile device and etc. I'm just looking for a workaround if I want to offer such feature in the given situation.

Comment: is this [2 bowls of rice, 1 egg, 1 tbsp soy sauce] array?

Comment: @Madhumitha No it's a string. I wrapped with `[]` just for display. I've removed it in the question to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you need ?

```
extension Float {
    var cleanValue: String {
        return self % 1 == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
    }
}

let item = "1 bowls of rice, 0.5 egg, 0.5 tbsp soy sauce"

func computeServing(inputString: String, servingCount:Int) -> String {
    var components = item.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    for idx in 0..<components.count {
        if let integer = Int(components[idx]){
            components[idx] = String(integer * servingCount)
        } else if let float = Float(components[idx]){
            components[idx] = String((float * Float(servingCount)).cleanValue)
        }
    }

    return components.joinWithSeparator(" ")

}

computeServing(item, servingCount: 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following extracts the ingredient information from the string. Based on that you can manipulate the data and simply join the components again. (A little challenge for you remains ;) )

```
func extractInfo(text: String!) -> [(String, Double)] {

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(([0-9.]+)([^0-9]+))", options: [])
    let nsString = text as NSString
    let results = regex.matchesInString(text, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))

    return results.map {
        (nsString.substringWithRange($0.rangeAtIndex(3)), Double(nsString.substringWithRange($0.rangeAtIndex(2)))!)
    }
}

let input = "12 bowls of rice, 1 egg, 0.5 tbsp soy sauce"
extractInfo(input)
```

It outputs for the given input:

> [(" bowls of rice, ", 12), (" egg, ", 1), (" tbsp soy sauce", 0.5)]

Please note that the given code does no error handling at all. It force-unwraps the optional parsed Double and expects each regex match to contain 4 groups - all that should be checked before actually doing ti to avoid a program crash.